# Signal is connected to following multiple drivers

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, xilinx, hdl

I trying to run the following and I receive this error:

Here's the Verilog code:

```
module needle( input referrence,input  penalty,output index[7:0]);
//inout input_itemsets;
//input referrence;

//input penalty;
//output index;
parameter max_cols=8;
//
wire index[7:0];
wire referrence;
wire penalty;
//wire input_itemsets;
genvar i,idx;
generate
for( i = max_cols-4 ; i >= 0 ; i=i-1)
    for( idx = 0 ; idx <= i ; idx=idx+1)
        begin
             assign index[i] = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);
             //assign index = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);
            //input_itemsets[index] <= maximum( input_itemsets[index-1-max_cols]+ referrence[index],
            //input_itemsets[index-1] - penalty,
            //input_itemsets[index-max_cols] - penalty);

        end
   endgenerate

endmodule
```

and here's the warnings and errors I receive:

```
WARNING:HDLCompiler:413 - "/home/suriyha/Monajalal/needle_t1/needle.v" Line 39: Result of 4-bit expression is truncated to fit in 1-bit target.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1401 - "/home/suriyha/Monajalal/needle_t1/needle.v" Line 39: Signal  index[3] in unit needle is connected to following multiple drivers:
Driver 0: output signal of instance Power (PWR_1_o_BUF_9).
Driver 1: output signal of instance Ground (GND_1_o_BUF_8).
Driver 2: output signal of instance Ground (GND_1_o_BUF_6).
Driver 3: output signal of instance Ground (GND_1_o_BUF_4).
Driver 4: output signal of instance Ground (GND_1_o_BUF_11).
Module needle remains a blackbox, due to errors in its contents
WARNING:HDLCompiler:1499 - "/home/suriyha/Monajalal/needle_t1/needle.v" Line 21: Empty module <needle> remains a black box.
```

However the main code is "assign index = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);" but I decided to make "index" an array to avoid this problem, however I am yet running to it. So no matter if index is an array or just a variable I yet have this multiple value problem.

Also the C version of the code is :

```
for( idx = 0 ; idx <= i ; idx++){
    index = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);
    input_itemsets[index]= maximum( input_itemsets[index-1-max_cols]+ referrence[index],
    input_itemsets[index-1] - penalty,
     input_itemsets[index-max_cols] - penalty);
 }
```

I would also like to know if we can have a nested loop like what we have in its C counter part in the Verilog version or how to avoid the "multiple driver" problem in this case??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your Verilog code, most `index` bits are constants that are either double driven(`x`) or not driven(`z`):
`index[7:0]:zzzxxxx1`

The explanation is the following. The outer loop is from 4 to 0, which means `index[7:5]` are undriven(`z`). The inner loop is from 0 to `i`, which unrolls to something like the following:

```
assign index[4] = (0 + 1) * max_cols + (4 + 1 - 0);
assign index[4] = (1 + 1) * max_cols + (4 + 1 - 1);
...
assign index[1] = (0 + 1) * max_cols + (1 + 1 - 0);
assign index[1] = (1 + 1) * max_cols + (1 + 1 - 1);
assign index[0] = (0 + 1) * max_cols + (0 + 1 - 0);
```

So `index[4:1]` are double driven(`x`), and only `index[0]` has a single driver.

Compiled code with a test here: [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/47)

Answer (score 2):

`output index[7:0]` is an unpacked array of bits. The C equivelent to this is `bool *index[8]`. I believe you want `output [7:0] index`.

The issues:

> WARNING:HDLCompiler:413 - "/home/suriyha/Monajalal/needle_t1/needle.v" Line 39: Result of 4-bit expression is truncated to fit in 1-bit target.

Is refering to `index[i] = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);`. only the lsb ob the left hand expression will be assigned to `index[i]` (a 1-bit value). The right hand side assignee value should be at least a 4-bit value.

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:1401 - "/home/suriyha/Monajalal/needle_t1/needle.v" Line 39: Signal  index[3] in unit needle is connected to following multiple drivers: [...]

This error is because of the way you are using your generate statement. If you unravel your for-loops, you will see multiple `assign index[3] = ...`. I suggest replacing the gerenate block with a `always @(*)` block. Output should be `output reg` and intermediate values such as `i` and `idx` should be an `integer` type or some form a of a packed `reg` (ex `reg [7:0] i, idx;`).

**Other issue that stand out.**

It looks like `input_itemsets` is intended to be an `inout`. Inouts in Verilog are very different then C. In Verilog there should should be one driver at any given time. Conflicting drivers will result in X. It is best make a copy with sample state and a hand-off for during a drive stage.

What you want may look something like the following:

http://www.edaplayground.com/s/6/48

Comment: Well, the reason I am using an array for index is that when I was using "index" variable alone I received "multiple driver" too, so I thought if I use an array it might solve it. However the reason I am using genvar and generate is that integer is not synthesizable thatt is why I am using "genvar" for i and j. So what do you suggest for doing to have a synthesizable design in this case?

Comment: If your synthesizer is not smart enough to optimize out an `integer` used as a for-loop index, then do something like `reg signed [7:0]` instead. Check out the edaplayground, links to in my and others answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used generate sentence just to make connections between blocks, and I am seeing that you are assigning to index[] idx and i, which are not signals(these do not have driver)... I mean those values wont make index to get values. You should think when writing a verilog code if that means something in hardware. I mean the parameter and the for's are not something in hardware
If you want index to get values you have to use a signal, which has a driver(inputs, wires).

Comment: Try using inputs to assign something to index. Not idx/i

Comment: I wanted to convert this C  `index = (idx + 1) * max_cols + (i + 1 - idx);` program to HDL level. This is not something I wanted to write from the scratch but apparently we cannot assign loop indices to a variable by assign statement, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want a synthesizable code you can't. But you can if it is not synthesizable.

Comment: And i just have a thought about the errors you are getting, since you are asigning to the output a variable, this signal wont change (i.e betweeen 1 and 0) and that's why you are getting  errors that the signals are always connected do VCC or GND.