# Signal is connected to following multiple drivers in verilog

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Company: 

// Engineer: 

// 

// Create Date:    20:07:59 12/16/2017 

// Design Name: 

// Module Name:    keyscan 

// Project Name: 

// Target Devices: 

// Tool versions: 

// Description: 

//

// Dependencies: 

//

// Revision: 

// Revision 0.01 - File Created

// Additional Comments: 

//

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module keyscan(key, clk, reset, keyout);

    input [9:0] key;

    input clk, reset;

    output reg [127:0] keyout;





    reg [3:0] keyp [31:0] ;

    reg [3:0] key_bcd;



    integer i, count;


///////ERROR help me ㅠ.ㅠ
    always @ (posedge reset) begin

        if(reset==1) begin

            for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)begin

                keyp[i] <= 4'hF;

            end

                key_bcd <= 4'b1111;

                count <= 0;

        end

    end



    always @ (*) begin

        case(key)

            10'b0000000001 :

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0000; //0

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0000000010 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0001; // 1

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0000000100 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0010; // 2

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0000001000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0011; // 3

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0000010000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0100; // 4

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0000100000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0101; // 5

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0001000000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0110; // 6

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0010000000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b0111; // 7

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b0100000000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b1000; // 8

                count = count + 1;

            end

            10'b1000000000 : 

            begin 

                key_bcd = 4'b1001; // 9

                count = count + 1;

            end



            default : key_bcd = 4'b1111; // ??

        endcase



        if(count == 32)

            count = 0;

    end





    always@ (count) begin

        if(key_bcd != 4'b1111)

            keyp[count-1] <= key_bcd;

    end



    always@ (posedge clk)begin

        keyout = {keyp[31],124'hfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff};

    end



endmodule
```

> ERROR ㅠ.ㅠ
>   HDLCompiler:1401 - "C:\Users\com603\Desktop\verilog\aqx\keyscanf.v" Line 44: Signal keyp[31][3] in unit keyscanf is connected to following multiple drivers:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signal is connected to following multiple drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114981/signal-is-connected-to-following-multiple-drivers)

Comment: @Qui it is a different issues. OP has 2 always blocks which drive the same signal.

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 always block which drive the same register `keyp`:

```
always @ (posedge reset) begin
    if(reset==1) begin
        for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)begin
            keyp[i] <= 4'hF; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        end
       ...
```

and

```
always@ (count) begin
    if(key_bcd != 4'b1111)
        keyp[count-1] <= key_bcd;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
end
```

In simulation it will produce unpredictible result since the last driver will win. But there is no way to say which one is the last. Synthesis should complain about it.

You need to find a way to combine both statements in the same always block.

First of all you need to synchronize your code using clock. You even have `clk` as an input, so use with `@(posedge clk)` in your block.

I guess something like the following should work:

```
always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset==1) begin
        for(i=0; i<32; i=i+1)begin
            keyp[i] <= 4'hF;
        end
            key_bcd <= 4'b1111;
    end
    else if(key_bcd != 4'b1111)
        keyp[count-1] <= key_bcd;
end
```

Comment: Another issue is `count` has asynchronous feedback. It needs to be flopped

Comment: @Greg right, count is another issue. And it is also multiply driven. I removed it from my example..